# I need clarification of goverment positions question on the Canada visa application

Tags: canada, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am filling in form [IMM5257B](https://www.wpvs.com/UserFiles/File/Canada_IMM5257B_Schedule_1_Form.pdf) for my father.

There is section `7 Government Positions`, where it mentioned as `Have you ever held any government positions (such as civil servant, judge, police officer, mayor, member of parliament, hospital administrator)? Do not use abbreviations.`

My father was in a government position, but not in any of the positions mentioned within the backets; he was in the government's agriculture deparment.

I don't think I have to mention his agriculture department experiences in this section but, before submit his application, I just want to confirm.

Is Section 7 is only for `civil servant, judge, police officer, mayor, member of parliament, hospital administrator` or is it for any/all government positions?

Comment: Most likely, he would have been a civil servant, which is just another way of referring to someone who works (or worked) for a government (or ministry)...

Comment: They cannot possibly list out every government position that's out there in any specific country. If its a government position, then you have to list it out.

Comment: @DipenShah it has other columns as `Level of jurisdiction`, that confuse me, because `jurisdiction` apply only in case of the position mentioned in bracket.

Comment: @Dorothy, my father was `Associate Research Scientist` in `State Agriculture University` in one of the state in India. In India, agriculture position is not consider as `civil servant` position. Still confuse what to write in it :(

Comment: IMO he would not be a civil servant; he was an university employee.

Comment: @Lafada Level of jurisdiction would be city, county, town, province, federal, etc.

Comment: @Max yes, he was university employee, should I have to mention that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is "Have you ever held any government positions?" The list of positions says they are examples, which means they are not exhaustive. You should list your father's position.

Apart from any other considerations, there is no disadvantage to listing a position they are not interested in, whereas failing to list a relevant position could get your application thrown out for fraud.